# Mobile app yammer integration

Tags: android, ios, yammer

we are implementing a mobile application (Android and iOS) and require the user to view the yammer availability (check if the user is online). All the communication will be via the yammer application given that it's installed in the device.

Please clarify how this can achieved.

Comment: Long ago I integrated Yammer with my app. I followed the link given below.Hope it works for you as well - https://zapier.com/zapbook/android/yammer/

Comment: @AnswerDroid I visited the mentioned link, but could not find anything. Please help.

Comment: @SKP I did this long ago. However, did you tried the answer which is marked in this question?

Comment: @AnswerDroid Yeah, I tried looking into the code you pointed, but that app is crashing as there is no MainActivity in the app and the launcher activity is mentioned as MainActivity. The actual problem is that i don't have a clear idea how Yammer works with Android. Do we need to create our own UI for Dashboard and Inbox?

Comment: @SKP Yes, what I remember it provides set of APIs and we needed to create our own Screens

Comment: @AnswerDroid Thanks a lot! It would really help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the yammer REST API to achieve this functionality. Which can be found;
https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/usersjson-1

The [yammer-android-sdk](https://github.com/Nyceane/Yammer-Android-SDK)

would be helpful for the anyone whose doing the integration.

Comment: In this SDK code block: 
if(uri.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase(scheme)) 
never execute